# Redux crud implementation using rest call

Tags: redux

Iam trying to implement redux crud operations using rest service calls. Iam able to fetch details but unable to perform create update and delete operations in rest service call.

Can you please help me out with sample template

Comment: please add your code to better understand the problem

Comment: Iam using test api call to perform CRUD operations using redux.  http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users  this is the rest call used. In the Actions i have written fetchActions its working fine. Rest of the operations is not working

Comment: still need code to identify the isse